# CSS: Full Left & Right Bleed Images

Tags: html, css

On my homepage, I'm trying to make three images span the entire width of the browser window. See my site here: http://accelfoods.com. I want the last 3 images on the page (About AccelFoods, Industry Engagement, Portfolio Companies) to be the same width as the image directly under the navigation.

I've figured out how to control #page-body and can make the image go to the edge of the left side (like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlhNF.jpg). But I don't know how to make the white space on the right disappear.

I've commented this CSS out for now until I figure it out, but here's what I'm using to manipulate the images:

```
#page-body {

margin-left: 0px;

padding-right: 0px;
border-right: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;

overflow-x:hidden;
width: 100%;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try to add `box-sizing:border-box;` and remove all that `margin-right/left` and `padding-right` just use `margin:0; padding:0;` ... see will that work. btw. next time provide and html, too.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, remove "max-size" parameter from:

```
#banner-area, #page-body, #page-footer{
    width: auto;
}
```

then add this:

```
.sqs-block-content {
    width: 100%;
}

.image-block-outer-wrapper.layout-caption-hidden {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.sqs-block-image .intrinsic {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: none !important;
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

but there's also script adding a strict width for this intrinsic class, I cannot see that from the first glance, it's kind of encription there and it will take time to understand it... though, the suggestion I'm giving you here definitely overrides the script.

P.S.
I would reccomend you not to use this kind of sitebuilder(s) (you definitely use some kind of) - because there's pretty tough class generator and if you need further updates there -you'll get pretty much more troubles.